# simple xml php need help

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm having trouble with simple xml to assign it as variable.

Here is my code:

```
$config = '../XML/config.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($config);
$cnt = count($xml->children());

for($i=0;i<=$cnt;$i++) {
    foreach($xml->item[$i]->attributes() as $a => $b) {

        echo $a."<br />"; //result

    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portfolio tooltip="click to view">
    <item path="approvals/710.png" title="ASC Approval" description="Oct 25, 2010 approval letter from ASC." link="approvals/710.PDF" target="_blank" />
    <item path="approvals/711.png" title="Citi Approval" description="Nov 1, 2010 approval letter from CitiMortgage." link="approvals/711.PDF" target="_blank" />
    <item path="approvals/712.png" title="Citi / Freddie" description="Nov 9, 2010 approval letter from Freddie Mac for CitiMortgage." link="approvals/712.PDF" target="_blank" />
    <item path="approvals/713.png" title="BoA Approval" description="Nov 9, 2010 approval letter from Bank of America." link="approvals/713.PDF" target="_blank" />
    <item path="approvals/714.png" title="Pentagon" description="Nov 10, 2010 approval letter from Pentagon FCU." link="approvals/714.PDF" target="_blank" />
    <item path="approvals/715.png" title="PNC Approval" description="Nov 10, 2010 approval letter from PNC Mortgage." link="approvals/715.PDF" target="_blank" />
</portfolio>
```

I need the result in a variable form. I try this one and got an error

```
$config = '../XML/config.xml';
$attr = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_file($config);
$cnt = count($xml->children());

for($i=0;i<=$cnt;$i++) {
    foreach($xml->item[$i]->attributes() as $a => $b) {

        $attr[$a] = $b;

    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($attr);
echo "</pre>";
```

But I got this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\slide\admin\admin.php on line 51
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to post your xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've a typo in your for loop: `for($i=0;i<=$cnt;$i++) {` should be `for($i=0;i<$cnt;$i++) {` (no `=`)

As an aside, $xml->item supports foreach, so you could do:

```
foreach( $xml->item as $item )
{
    foreach( $item->attributes() as $a => $b )
    {
        $attr[ $a ] = $b;
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of working with the language constructs natively, it avoids the need for `count`, and it completely avoids the possibility of a `<=` typo.

Also, just as a heads up, if you have multiple nodes with an "id" attribute, only one will end up in `$attr`. If this is what you need, that's fine, but it is something which can cause headache if you don't notice it.